# Emulating waveform at lower current

Tags: resistors, power-electronics, inductor

I have a circuit that sends pulses to a fuel injector. This injector can be precisely modeled with a 3.3 mH inductor and a 2.7 Ω resistor. The injector consumes 1.4 A when it operates.

I would like to make a circuit board that replaces the injector but when stimulated in the same way gives the same waveform.

The problem I am running into is that this requires a large inductor and 5 W resistors, which are bulky and not tunable. If I want tuning then looking at 5 W variable resistors they are very, very expensive.

Is there a way I can recreate a hardware-based simulation of the fuel injector without needing high current parts?

UPDATE - based on user253751 's suggestion I looked at the average power consumption in simulation. At an engine speed of 6,500 RPM over a period of one second it works out to be 0.3334 W or 1/3 W.

[image]

Comment: A quick search shows that Mouser have [5 W wirewound resistors](https://www.mouser.ie/c/passive-components/resistors/wirewound-resistors/wirewound-resistors-through-hole/?power%20rating=5%20W&termination%20style=Radial) from €0.75.

Comment: @Transistor For the cost I was referring to the variable resistors at 5W. I will make that clearer. Tunable is better.

Comment: I bet the injector isn't dissipating 5W *all the time*. You can probably get away with a much smaller resistor and inductor. Physically smaller, that is - you'll still need the right resistance and inductance. Size them based on the *average* power dissipation, and I bet that will work fine.

Comment: What tuning range is needed? You can arrange it so the bulk of the power is dissipated in a fixed resistor.

Comment: @user253751 That is a good point. I will see if ngspice can calculate for me for different engine speeds to find the worse case.

Comment: @user253751 1.5mH -> 3.3mH and 2 Ohms -> 4 Ohms would be nice to have.

Comment: Why would you not use an actual fuel injector???

Comment: @KyleB We have been doing but for various reasons we want to switch to this approach, but that is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: 5W variable resistors are not particularly expensive BTW....   Should be like $10 or thereabouts.  Are you looking at "rheostats"????   If not, you should be.

Comment: For the resistive portion you could try feeding an adjustable voltage to a MOSFET. Shouldn't be too hard to find a MOSFET that can dissipate 4W pulses. (unlike another question where someone needed to dissipate 1500W)

Comment: _"Is there a way I can recreate a hardware-based simulation of the fuel injector without needing high current parts?"_ - yes, but it will draw less current. Will this be a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took @user253751 's advice and used spice to work out the RMS power usage at 6500 RPM. It came to 837mA. I then found 680uH inductors with at least this current rating measuring 12mm x 12mm and decided to connect some of those in series. Together the series resistance adds up to the correct value so no additional power resistor needed. The result is small enough to integrate onto my board.